# jQuery hover function doesn't work

Tags: jquery, html

Im trying to do this, a simple hover function.

#### HTML:

```
<ul class="ulComprar">
  <li class="liEspecial"><p>Hello!</p><li>
</ul>
```

#### jQuery:

```
$('.ulComprar').hover(function () {
  $('li.liEspecial').css("display", "normal"), function () {
    $('li.liEspecial').css("display", "none");
  }
});
```

#### CSS:

```
.ulComprar {    
    display: inline-block; 
    list-style: none;
    font-style: oblique; 
    font: bold; 
    font-family: Calibri; 
    font-size: 14px;
}

li.liEspecial {
     display: none;
}
```

But this doesn't work.

Comment: `display: normal`, where did you get this?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your HTML code looks something like this:

```
<ul class="ulComprar">
  <li>Milk</li>
  <li class="liEspecial">Eggs</li>
  <li>Bread</li>
</ul>
```

Then you could use the following query snippet to show and hide element li.liEspecial:

```
$('.ulComprar').hover(
  function() {
    $('.liEspecial', this).hide();    // hides li on mouse enter
  }, function() {
    $('.liEspecial', this).show();    // shows li on mouse leave
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

we don't have `display: normal;`. the default `display` for [li](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_li.asp) is `list-item`. try this code:

```
$('.ulComprar').on('mouseenter', function () {
    $('.liEspecial').css("display", "list-item");
}).on('mouseleave', function () {
    $('.liEspecial').css("display", "none");
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yhhoL6ce/1/)